# Add Gradient Color Top of Transparent Header Only?

Tags: css, header

I'd like to darken the top of my homepage header.

Here is an example:  www.reachlocal.com

You will notice that only a % of the top of their header is darker so that their nav menu sticks out more.

I've searched all over Google trying to find a gradient top-header overlay/opacity/etc. css for this.  I only want to apply this to my homepage.  Any takers that can help me?

Mike

Answer (score 1):

Its a bit difficult for beginner, i will need your code to help you more but here is a hint:

You can use the pseudo class ::before here is an example:

```
  .navtop::before{
              position: absolute;
               content:"";
               height:100px;
              width:100%;
              top:0;
              left:0;
              background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,1), 
                                      rgba(0,0,0,0));
              Z-index:-1;
               }
```

Now should appear a dark/transparent background for your navigation, just use instead of .navtop your class

Edit: I forgot to add position:absolute

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like that?

```
#gradientbar{
background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,0));
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100vw;
height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: I believe so.  But is the #gradientbar going to class my homepage header?  I put in this code but it did not change anything.  Also FYI:  My homepage is scrolling presentation slides using a transparent special header.

Comment: try putting `<div id="gradientbar"></div>` before header div in your html file

Comment: Okay, I will try that.  Thanks man.

Comment: no problem, tell me if it worked after you try!

Comment: Cool I will.  Gotta go get lunch.  I'm starving!  One more quick question:  In www.reachlocal.com you notice the different colors in their top bar?  What's that called if i wanted to mess with something like that?  Any clue?  I did a Google search but came up empty handed.  Appreciate your time.  - Mike

Comment: [link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rRPWVY) try this!

Comment: You're awesome man!  Appreciate all your help! - Mike

Comment: glad to have helped!!